# How to wait for redux dispatch to finish before another dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch-async

```
addOrder = (event) => {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'POST_ORDER',
      payload: this.state.newOrder,
    });
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'GET_ORDER_DETAILS',
      payload: this.props.store.orders.length + 2,
    });
    this.props.history.push(`/orders/${this.props.store.orders.length + 2}`);
  };
```

```
function* postOrder(action) {
  try {
    yield put({ type: 'ERROR_RESET' });
    yield axios.post('/api/orders', action.payload);
    yield put({
      type: 'GET_ALL_ORDERS',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    yield put({
      type: 'ERROR_MSG',
      payload: "Sorry we couldn't save your order. Please try again.",
    });
  }
}
```

```
function* getOrderDetails(action) {
  try {
    yield put({ type: 'ERROR_RESET' });
    const response = yield axios.get(`/api/orders/${action.payload}`);
    yield put({
      type: 'SET_ORDER_DETAILS',
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    yield put({
      type: 'ERROR_MSG',
      payload: 'There was a problem loading order. Please try again.',
    });
  }
}
```

My main problem is when the `addOrder` is fired `POST_ORDER` doesn't finish by the time `GET_ORDER_DETAILS` fires. My goal is that the `POST_ORDER` will finish, then the dispatch to `GET_ORDER_DETAILS` should fire and when the page redirects the new data is there.

Right now `GET_ORDER_DETAILS` is firing off before the first dispatch is finished resulting in undefined data when it redirects. Sorry I'm new to react and redux and I've been googling trying to find a solution but not having much luck. Any help and pointing me in the right direction to tackle this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using certain middleware like redux-thunk or saga ?